# Spotlight Doesn't Properly Show Preference Panes

Tags: spotlight, system-settings

I'm having an issue where Spotlight isn't properly showing results for System Preference panels. When I search for a preference panel by name (*e.g.* `Sharing` or `Network`), I don't get any System Preferences results. If I search for "pref", I get a list of preference panes, like this:

[image: spotlight results]

Even typing the name as it appears there (*e.g.* `SharingPref.prefPane` or a subset thereof) doesn't get a result.

The only exception is that third party preference panes do appear correctly (albeit still with the `.prefPane` extension.

I've tried forcing a re-index, both by [Apple's method](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2409?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), and `sudo mdutil -E /`, and neither has fixed this behaviour. I don't recall when it started exactly, but I think it may have been ever since getting my new iMac (running 10.8), which was set up via Migration Assistant from my old MBP running 10.7.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have disabled everything except `Applications`, `Systems Preferences`, `Contacts`, `Events & To Dos` and `Developer`. Usually I search for files and documents via Finder. Now it properly shows preferences panes while searching.

Also you can drag categories in `Spotlight` preferences to change result priority.